# Inverted commas used around a letter or single word

Tags: punctuation

In a sentence we find a word in inverted commas or a single letter. Why?
Example 1: My 'first' experience of ...
Example 2: The letter 'g' in the word gnaw is silent

Comment: In this example the author wants to emphasize on the word *first*. He could have used double quotes instead, but he might have had them reserved for some other things.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72307/who-coined-the-term-scare-quotes-and-why-is-the-word-scare-used and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/whats-the-difference-between-using-single-and-double-quotation-marks-inverted-c?rq=1

Comment: @Mari-LouA I disagree that this is a duplicate of the 3rd ref you quote: that Q. does not address Ex.2 in this Q.. Nor does either of the other 2 refs. Voting to leave open for that reason.

Comment: @TrevorD agreed the two questions are not identical but they are very similar. Could we at least agree that any future questions on why inverted commas or quotes are used to highlight words, should be closed. Moreover, there should be a way for the system to recognize "quotation marks"/"quotes"/"inverted commas"/"speech marks"/"double quotes" as being related to each other, otherwise we will continue to see similar questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't disagree with anything you've said. I just thought that Ex.2 deserved an answer - which it's now had anyway.

Answer (score 5):

They have different meanings

- [Scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation#Scare_quotes)

  > They are placed around a word or phrase to indicate that it is not used in the fashion that the writer would personally use it. In contrast to the nominal typographic purpose of quotation marks, the enclosed words are not necessarily quoted from another source. When read aloud, various techniques are used to convey the sense, such as prepending the addition of "so-called" or a similar word or phrase of disdain, using a sarcastic or mocking tone, or using air quotes, or any combination of the above
- [Inverted commas](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/inverted-commas)

  > to mark off a word or phrase that’s being discussed

Answer (score 0):

Words are often written within quotes to indicate that someone has already used it earlier.
Letters are written within quotes since writing just a letter (apart from *I*) isn't grammatically  correct. A letter by itself has no meaning. So, to use them in sentences, quotes are required.

Comment: I think it's necessary to make clear that your first sentence indicates incorrect usage (however often encountered).

Comment: Could you please point out the mistake?

Comment: Simply that quotes should never be used for emphasis. They quote.